# How to get biking and transit information by google map sdk for ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to create a Swift app similar to google map. I use Google map `SDK` for `iOS`. I want to get `Biking`, `Transit`, and `Traffic` information .For `Traffic` information, I use this  :

`mapView.isTrafficEnabled = true`

How can I do that for `Biking` and `Transit` ?

```
           [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]